# Function which removes html color from a string with sscanf

Tags: html, c++, colors

I've a big dilemma how can I do a condition to remove this type of color from my string (ex: {dd2e22}) using sscanf, which is only func I want to use. So the string provided will be some random text:

```
Te{dd2e22}xt is {3f53ec}here
```

The condition what I tried

```
sscanf(buf,"%[^\{[0-9a-fA-F]{6,8}\}]s",output);
```

This isn't working, the result are only first character "T".

Comment: You could include a format specifier for hexadecimal, 6 digits, and tell `scanf` to ignore that specifier, `"%*6x"`.  The key is the `'*'` in the format specifier says not to assign the value, thus skipping it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the format specifier:
`"%*6X"`

Analysis:
% -- starts a format specifier.
* -- tells `scanf` not to assign field to variable.
6x -- says that field is 6 hex digits.

See [`scanf` format specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)

Answer (score 0):

> result are only first character "T".

Well, the next character is 'e', which matches the set `\{[0-9a-fA-F]{6,8}\` and thus doesn't match the inverted set specified by '^'.

This task can be achieved with a regular expression. The standard library provides you with appropriate tools in the `<regex>` header.

Comment: Ok, then which expression I need to use?